# how to load gallery images from arraylist android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

i have a dynamic value of images that are stored in a arraylist thumbnails that i  want to show in the gallery. the string values inside the arraylist are the image paths of the thumbnails (e.g /mnt/sdcard/MyApp/Thumbnails/thumb1.png)....

i have this code:

```
class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;

    private ArrayList<String> thumbnails = new ArrayList<String>();


    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> thumb) {
        mContext = c;
        System.out.print("thumbs: " + thumb);
        thumbnails = thumb;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return thumbnails.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }



   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
      BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
      options.inSampleSize = 0;
      Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thumbnails.get(i), options);
      imageView.setImageBitmap(bm); 
      imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(150, 150));
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
      return imageView;
    }
}
```

---

and this code/method to display gallery view from the main class:

```
Gallery gal1;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    gal1 = (Gallery) this.findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
}

private void setDisplay(){

    OnItemClickListener myItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      };
    };

  gal1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, _paththumb));
}
```

how can i load images from arraylist?

UPDATED:
i used your code zrgui and logcat said:

```
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.widget.Gallery.setUpChild(Gallery.java:769)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.widget.Gallery.makeAndAddView(Gallery.java:738)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.widget.Gallery.layout(Gallery.java:622)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.widget.Gallery.onLayout(Gallery.java:336)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1238)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1044)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1205)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:909)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333) 
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-07 12:31:56.046: E/AndroidRuntime(3572):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your image paths in _paththumb when you initialize the ImageAdapter then it should all be ok. Also don't forget to call setDisplay().

You should also optimize the getView method there because you're creating new ImageViews instead of reusing them (thus invalidating the whole purpose of the adapter).

Edit: the getView optimization:

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          ImageView imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
          if (imageView == null) {
             imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
          }
          BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
          options.inSampleSize = 0;
          Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thumbnails.get(i), options);
          imageView.setImageBitmap(bm); 
          imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(150, 150));
          imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
          return imageView;
    }
```

Comment: that's what i'm having trouble now, can't figure out how to change the getView(). can someone help me here?

Comment: where do the variable i at thumbnails.get(i) came from?

Comment: i solved it now, thanks for your reply that lead me to the right path